# Gem allow you to create system administration scripts with 'Ruby' on linux systems

Tags: ruby, linux, automation, rubygems, system-administration

I've been making automation scripts for windows using powershell, and I want to do the same for my linux system, I am looking for the best way to do this, like using a specific gem that conclude all the relevant operations i.e, base administration commands such as those for managing file systems, querying system information as CPU (similar to WMI). I want it to be object-oriented. I couldn't find any gem that does that.